# Python3 - regex compilation for traceroute

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a Python script which will filter and select the relevant IP Addresses from a traceroute input...

This is the input:

```
Hostname#traceroute 10.0.0.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.0.0.1

 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec
11 10.0.0.3 115 msec
   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec
```

I'm creating a list from this:

```
hosts = ['Hostname#traceroute 10.0.0.1', 'Type escape sequence to abort.', 'Tracing the route to 10.0.0.1', ' 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec', '11 10.0.0.3 115 msec', '   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec']
```

Now, my goal is to filter out the elements which I dont need, and basically only keep the last 3 lines:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\s\s\s|\s\d\s|\s\d\d)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
ip = list(filter(pattern.match, hosts))
```

I've tested the regex itself in online generators, so that should be OK, but in Python I'm getting an empty list, which indicates that there is no match.

I've spent hours finding out what the problem is, but I wasn't able to. It was either an empty list or an error like this, eventho I've converted it to strings:

```
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I think you could use findall. Instead of using a lookbehind you could match the whole string instead and use a kind of broad match to identity you numbers [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJU3KW/1/) or 

[Python](https://ideone.com/66O1v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two little things going wrong here,

First is, in your regex, in look behind alternation, this `|\s\d\d)` is not correct as the line is "11 " hence your regex should be `|\d\d\s)`

And second problem is, you are using **match** instead of **findall**. Match is used to match whole line but your regex can't match whole line, so using findall in this `filter(pattern.findall, hosts)` solves the problem.

If you wanted your code to work with **match** instead of **findall**, try using this regex `.*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s.*` which will match only last three lines and give you your intended result.

Run your improvised code and see how it prints the output you expected,

```
import re

s = '''Hostname#traceroute 10.0.0.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.0.0.1

 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec
11 10.0.0.3 115 msec
   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec'''

hosts = re.findall(r'(.*)\n*',s)

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\s\s\s|\s\d\s|\d\d\s)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
ip = list(filter(pattern.findall, hosts))

print(ip)
```

Which prints the last three lines as you expected,

```
[' 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec', '11 10.0.0.3 115 msec', '   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec']
```

Also, if you just wanted to print last three lines, you could exploit the fact that in last three lines the IP was followed by a space and hence you could have also used a simplified regex like this `pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s")` which would have also given you last three lines.

**Edit: codes for regex having space after IP**

```
import re

s = '''Hostname#traceroute 10.0.0.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.0.0.1

 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec
11 10.0.0.3 115 msec
   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec'''

hosts = re.findall(r'(.*)\n*',s)

pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s")
ip = list(filter(pattern.findall, hosts))

print(ip)
```

Which prints,

```
[' 1 10.0.0.2 0 msec 6 msec 0 msec', '11 10.0.0.3 115 msec', '   10.0.0.4 115 msec 116 msec']
```

Comment: Thanks; the "findall" method seems to be working. I've tried the one with the space on the last 3, that didnt work for some reason.

Comment: @vikdean: Glad to know it worked for you. The one having space after those IPs in last three line also works. Let me edit and answer and add codes for them as well.

Comment: A bigger mistake is reinventing stuff which has already been reinvented many times. Google for "traceroute python" instead.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new traceroute application; all I want to do is process the traceroute output and resolve all of the IPs in the path from a CSV with hostnames.
I've looked, but couldn't find a script that does this already.